# How to match 3 tables using R? One table has more than one correspondence

Tags: r, match

How to match 3 tables using R? I have table A with columns X, Y and Z, table B with columns X and F and table C with columns F and G. I would like to have one with columns F,Y,Z,G. In table C, I can have some Fs with more than one G and F

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a 'merge' situation

In general 
`merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)), by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all)`

You should do something like

`AB <- merge(x = A, y = B, by = "X")
ABC <- merge(x = AB, y = C, by = "F")`

You should check the 'all' parameters to keep or not the non-matching records and then subset ABC to keep only the columns F,Y,Z, and G.